# QGIS: SPIT plugin not loading

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

Using QGIS 2.12 Lyon on a Mac (Intel, 2013). I check the SPIT line in plug-ins, but the plugin does not appear in the menu bar as promised. Log out, restart, nothing helps. Other plug-ins work fine and appear in the bar. Ideas?

Comment: Not a Mac user but could you access the **SPIT** plugin from the toolbar: _Database > Spit_?

Comment: The SPIT plugin is really old and in the process of being depreciated. You should try the DB Manager plugin or just the browser for data loading.

Comment: `process of being depreciated` Will be gone in the next release.